# Postgrad Mathematics

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow, area51

I've proposed an intermediate level site between Mathematics and Mathoverflow to see if there is any support for this at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46802/postgrad-mathematics

I think that if an intermediate level site took off then I would find it more interesting than either Mathoverflow or Mathematics.

Edit: Proposal obviously had no support so is now deleted.

Comment: I don't see the niche that you're proposing to fill.

Comment: I cannot imagine what sort of questions would fit such a site...

Comment: @Mariano, maybe homework questions from Math PhD students --- rejected as homework at MO, too advanced to find any takers at m.se. But this assumes that the intermediate site would attract more people who want to answer such questions than m.se does.

Comment: Grat idea! But eventually we will need two more sites. One for the questions on the boundary of MSE and Postgrad Math and one for the questions on the boundary between Postgrad Math and MO. This will prompt of course the need for additional such sites to deal with the new boundaries and eventually everyone will have their own mathematics Q&A at exactly the right level where we can post and answer our own questions in joyful solitude...

Comment: @Michael: So if time was infinite (and the human race would exist indefinitely) we might have a chain of sites, ordered by level with the order type of the rationals? Seeing how at each point there are only finitely many humans, at the limit stage there would be countably many (assuming continuity) so maybe every person would have their own site. Wouldn't it be just easier if people open blogs *now* and post these questions on their blogs, then?

Comment: @Asaf Don't be ridiculous. On a blog, there is no incentive to answer your own questions. On AsafK.M.SE on the other hand, you get reputation for answering your own questions, can upvote and downvote, and get suspend if you are not sufficiently nice to yourself.

Comment: As a PhD student, I ask a smattering of questions here and on MO. I have found little or no problems with getting answers where there are answers, both here and at MO. I would find another site would just muddy the waters. Just now it is simple: MO is for research-level questions. SE is for everything else. It is papers vs books. If I am looking for information which isn't going to be in a book, then MO. Otherwise, SE.

Comment: @Asaf: assuming hypothetical (as opposed to actual) human beings, Michael's process may not in fact terminate and would replicate the Dedekind cut. And we then finally see why even IPv6 is not enough.

Comment: I voted +1 because I think it is important that such an initiative gets announced here. So that people can **actually go visit Area 51 and express their opinions there**. In particular, you can [ask questions](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/8009/how-can-the-proposal-definition-for-postgrad-mathematics-be-improved) or offer critique of the proposal there, where it would be more on topic.

Comment: @vtt Perhaps you could post the content of your edit as an answer - so that the question does not remain unanswered and it is not bumped again by [Community user](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

Comment: ok. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The proposal has been deleted due to lack of support.